# env variables available in rails console but not in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu-12.04, vps

Never had such problem before with vps that I set up from zero, this one (Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit) was installed by some other developer.

**The problem**

in `.bashrc` file i have:

```
export FACEBOOK_ID=123456789
export FACEBOOK_SECRET=987654321
```

now in terminal if I type `env` I see these variables.
if I open `rails console` and type `ENV["FACEBOOK_ID"]` or `ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"]` I also can see the apropriate values.

The problem is that I have to use `FACEBOOK_ID` in the app in a view file and I do it with:

`<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_ID"] %>`

on local machine this returns the right value, in production on vps it returns nothing.
My idea is that the vps was not set up correctly, I couldnt find apache on it or ngnix, and the app is in `var/www/apps/app_name/`.

What could be wrong and how can I get this env variables in my template?

**update**

files available in root directory:

```
.bash_profile .bashrc .cshrc .zprofile .zshrc
```

Comment: Can you check the user running the application on the VPS has thoses variables set? like `system "whoami"` in ruby and the ensure that in the user returned home folder you have a file settings thoses variables

Comment: @mdemolin it's only root user on this vps

Comment: you should better avoid running application as root but that is another story. So if you ssh to you vps as root and try `$FACEBOOK_ID` what does it return?

Comment: yes, I know root is bad, but this is the way I got this vps, it is already configured this way.

Comment: @mdemolin `$FACEBOOK_ID` returns `-bash: 123456789: command not found`, it returns the right value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put it in local environment. What to do when you deploy the app? What to do when you want to develop another app on your local machine which use Facebook id as well?

Use Figaro gem. It's built for handling such case, env variables and private data. The env variables can be set in YAML file in app and won't be committed to repo. You won't regret.

Comment: I have a fb app for development, with any rails app that I work I use the same variable, for production environment I'll rename the variable in case I'll have more apps on the same vps, but as I know there will be only one.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the gem. Must be a great gem but the problem still remains opened. I have 2 more vp servers from other companies and I can access env variables in app. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: @rmagnum2002, sorry I don't know how to solve your problem about ENV on machine. I have never set ENV variable in machine, I always use this gem which is app independent. Maybe you delete machine setting and give this gem a try?

Comment: well, if I won't be able to fix this issue in next few hours I'll have to use this gem. Thank you very much.

Comment: that did it, and yes I won't regret it ;)